# I need to get from database the day and the results per day

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get information from a programme. I need that db retrives the days and all events and hours of each day.

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT *
                     FROM programme_day
                     WHERE year = 2019
                     AND event = 1
                     ORDER BY day ASC")->fetchAll();
 foreach ($data as $row)
 {
 ?>

 <div><?php echo date('d-m-Y', $row['day']); ?></div>

 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

I need the result to show like this:

```
TUESDAY JULY 23RD
10H00 - Lecture at FAUP - Arrhov Frick
11H00 - Lecture at FAUP - Johansen Skovsted
12H30 - Lunch break
14H00 - Workshop 

WEDNESDAY JULY 24TH
10H00 - Lecture at FAUP - Scheidegger Keller
11H00 - Lecture at FAUP - Nicolas Dorval-Bory
12H30 - Lunch break
14H00 - Workshop
19H00 - Lecture at FAUP 

THURSDAY JULY 25TH
10H00 - Lecture at FAUP - Dyvik Kahlen
11H00 - Lecture at FAUP - Fala
12H30 - Lunch break
14H00 - Workshop
22H00 - Submission of the Studios' Booklets
23H00 - End event
00H00 - Party
```

Comment: What is the result showing currently then and how does it differ from what you want? When your SQL statement has `SELECT *`, we have no idea what your column names are at all...

Comment: Hi @Martin thanks. My column names are day / hour / year / event / event_description

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how do you expect to see events when you don't echo them? And maybe you restrict your events with those WHERE event='1' but of course I am not sure because I have to see your whole database scheme. If you access your events you can display them also with a foreach within the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand. In my database I have a day/hour/year/event/event_description for each row. But if I echo all, the day will repeat every = events of that day. And what I need is to add day in the top and the events of that day, and mantain that structure for all days.

Comment: `$data = $pdo->query("SELECT *
                     FROM programme_day
                     WHERE year = 2019
                     AND event = 1
                     ORDER BY day ASC")->fetchAll();
 foreach ($data as $row)
 {
 ?>

 <div><?php echo date('d-m-Y', $row['day']); ?></div>

 <?php foreach($data as $row){ echo "<div>$row['event'] - $row['event_description']</div>"}
 }
 ?>`